# If statement in Oracle

Tags: oracle, select, if-statement, join

I need to create a query, that if a certain field is blank or null. I need to do a select statement to another table and retrieve the blank field . Could you please advise on a way to accomplish this. Below is the query. The field in question is BEAT.

```
        SELECT COALESCE(ADDRESSES.BEAT,Incident_addresses.beat)
        , COALESCE (ADDRESSES.SUB_BEAT,Incident_addresses.sub_beat)
      , ADDRESSES.STREET_NAME
 , ADDRESSES.STREET_NUMBER
 , ADDRESSES.SUB_NUMBER
 , WARRANT_PEOPLE_VW.LNAME
 , WARRANT_PEOPLE_VW.FNAME
 , WARRANT_PEOPLE_VW.DOB
 , WARRANT_PEOPLE_VW.RACE_RACE_CODE
 , WARRANT_PEOPLE_VW.SEX_SEX_CODE
 , WARRANT_PEOPLE_VW.CASE_NUMBER
 , E_WARRANTS.DATE_ISSUED
 , E_WARRANTS.TELETYPE_NUMBER
 , E_WARRANTS.ORDINANCE_VIOLATION
    FROM EJSDBA.ADDRESSES
   , POL_LEEAL.E_WARRANTS
     , POL_LEEAL.WARRANT_PEOPLE_VW,incident_people,Incident_addresses
     WHERE ADDRESSES.ADDRESS_ID =E_WARRANTS.ADDR_ADDRESS_ID
     AND E_WARRANTS.WARRANT_ID = WARRANT_PEOPLE_VW.WARRANT_ID
       AND WARRANT_PEOPLE_VW.NME_TYP_NAME_TYPE_CODE = 'P'
      AND WARRANT_PEOPLE_VW.AGNCY_CD_AGENCY_CODE = 'MCPD'
      AND WARRANT_PEOPLE_VW.WSC_CODE='A'
    AND EJSDBA.ADDRESSES.ADDRESS_ID= Incident_addresses.ADDRESS_ID
   and incident_people.inc_incident_id=Incident_addresses.incident_id
      ORDER BY ADDRESSES.BEAT
   , ADDRESSES.SUB_BEAT
   , ADDRESSES.STREET_NAME
   , ADDRESSES.STREET_NUMBER
       ;
```

Comment: Oracle supports ANSI SQL: CASE-WHEN-ELSE-END, COALESCE and has its own: DECODE, NVL, NVL2, etc. You can choose depending on your needs. Also there is no such a thing as a blank field in Oracle (SQL). All "blank fields" have a NULL value.

Comment: Can you use a select statemnt inside a COALESCE function, basically to say if the value is null select from another statement to give the field a value.

Comment: Can you give some details in your question about what you need? I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Basically if Addresses.Beat is null in this select statement. I want to do COALESECE ( Addresses.BEAT, Select Beat from incidents where incident_id=inc_incident_id) or something similiar to that

Comment: sOMETHING like this query, where if address.beat is null I addede the COALESCE query to substitue Incident_address.beat, please review:

Comment: SELECT COALESCE(ADDRESSES.BEAT,Incident_addresses.beat)
     , COALESCE (ADDRESSES.SUB_BEAT,Incident_addresses.sub_beat)
    
FROM EJSDBA.ADDRESSES
   , 
  AND EJSDBA.ADDRESSES.ADDRESS_ID= Incident_addresses.ADDRESS_ID
  and incident_people.inc_incident_id=Incident_addresses.incident_id

Comment: Yes that's what i was talking about :)

Comment: This case will return `Incident_addresses.beat` if `ADDRESSES.BEAT` is null, else will return `ADDRESSES.BEAT`, the same case for `ADDRESSES.SUB_BEAT`

Comment: Please clarify via post edits, not comments. Please read & act on [mcve]. Right now you don't even clearly say what you want a query to do, and you only give wrong code that doesn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a correlated subquery into a case expression, but you MUST reference the table inside the subquery to some values of the outer query so that the correct value can be located.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(ADDRESSES.BEAT, Incident_addresses.beat)
  , CASE
        WHEN Addresses.BEAT IS NULL THEN (
                SELECT
                    Beat
                FROM incidents inner_ref
                WHERE ???outer??.incident_id = inner_ref.id
                AND rownum = 1)
    END AS x
  , COALESCE(ADDRESSES.SUB_BEAT, Incident_addresses.sub_beat)
...
```

and that subquery MUST only return a single value (hence I have used "and rownum = 1".

(In Oracle 12 you could use FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY)